# The URL submitted contains the noindex tag google

Tags: wordpress, tags, noindex

I have a few links that I do not want to be indexed by Google. But googleshows me the following statistics error.
[image]

The weirdest part is that I configured these links not to be indexed.
Like I set a similar rule in robots.txt for my website. But google still catches them to me like error. Can anyone help me how to solve this problem?
My site is on a Linux platform and CMS WordPress system.

Comment: _configured these links not to be indexed_ How do you configured this links?